# Update target table only if its not null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a scenario, where we want to update 40 columns in oracle table. source is another oracle table.

1. They want to igonore the value of the column if it have null !!

example:

```
col1 col2 col3 
1    null  b
2    null  3
```

target table :

```
col1 col2 col3
1     a    null
2     b    null
```

after updted.

```
col1 col2 col3
1     a   b
2     b   3
```

note : we have to upate only if its not null ..

any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
update target_table tt
   set (col1, col2, col3) = ( select nvl(st.col1,tt.col1), 
                                     nvl(st.col2,tt.col2), 
                                     nvl(st.col3,tt.col3) 
                                from source_table st where st.primary_key = tt.primary_key )
 where exists ( select null 
                  from source_table st 
                 where st.primary_key = tt.primary_key
                   and (st.col1 is not null 
                        or st.col2 is not null 
                        or st.col3 is not null) );
```

Obviously you have to determine what the primary key is. I used "primary_key" only as an instructive guide.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
MERGE INTO TARGET_TABLE t
  USING SOURCE_TABLE s
    ON (s.COL1 = t.COL1)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.COL2 = NVL(t.COL2, s.COL2)
               t.COL3 = NVL(t.COL3, s.COL3);
```

I'm assuming here the COL1 is the column to use to find matching rows in TARGET_TABLE and SOURCE_TABLE.

Share and enjoy.